# php max execution time issue for bulk upload

Tags: php, mysql, yii, bigdata, bulkinsert

I have a problem with my bulk upload functionality. i am trying to upload 16000 records in a CSV file. Below is my code, i am using yii framework. but the issue is i am getting php max execution time.

This is a sample record

```
Gella,Rafalla,N/A,N/A,0 Pala da vences,13140,MIRAMAS,1,1926-04-25,N/A,LE TRNT BAT I 13,N/A,CEJEAN GINO,6,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
```

and there are 16 000 records as such.

```
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // save the record after few validation.
    }
}
```

as you can see i am going through the entire file at one shot. can i know what is the problem here to get maximum execution time error?

as of now, **to process 2000 records it takes me 6 minutes**. so it will take me **48 minutes approximately to complete this file upload** by saving records.

Appreciate any suggestions to write it in a better way.

Here is the full logic. saved it here as its too long. https://3v4l.org/QZeg2

here is the database tables that i use to check inside the while loop.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a579/3

There is a User Table, Custom Field table and Custom Value table. There is no data Views or Triggers or Procedures.

Comment: 1000 records..... where's 1000 records? You don't think that the 2nd argument to fgetcsv() is a number of records do you?

Comment: The validation and the save are what is likely to be taking time to execute, ie. the bit that you're not showing in your code

Comment: If you are saving this to the database, the reason it's taking so long is because you are spending 1 I/O of your disk for saving. This long execution time implies your hard disk is mechanical, so unless you are able to bulk the inserts within a transaction, it will be slow. Also, as Mark mentioned - the 2nd argument to fgetcsv is not the number of records so pay attention to that..

Comment: @RyanVincent - the sad fact is that the transfer rate plays no role if the disk spends 1 I/O per write. The transfer rate can be 100mb/sec, it will still be slow. The solution is to flush several thousands of inserts per 1 I/O and that's controlled by transactions. The code that's missing is what should be fixed and implement the mentioned mechanism.

Comment: `3v4l.org` is not for code sharing, please don't load servers of that guys, they are cool))

Comment: @RyanVincent No i am processing each row and doing validation and then updating the table.   this is the table structure but User table has more columns than defined here. that's all. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a579/3

There is a User Table, Custom Field table and Custom Value table. There is no data Views or Triggers or Procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your performance problem is the validation and the save, as mentioned in the comments.

But if your doing a **one-time import** here and your problem is not really the performance but the **maximum execution time**, you might try the CLI.

If you have your code already in yii, you can make a yii console application out of it:

Yii 1.1:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console

Yii 2:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html